# How many cards do I need to fully level up each unit type?

Tags: command-and-conquer-rivals

I know that the maximum level for units 15 and that the cards required to level up roughly double each time.

Currently my highest units are level 9 and I need 600 common cards, 180 rare cards and 30 epic cards to get to level 10.

By the above logic I would still need about 35,000 cards to get a common unit to max level, which seems ridiculously high.

The C&C Wiki page only lists the cards required for each unit up to level 5, has anyone figured out how many cards are actually required to max out each unit type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more searching only I found this table posted by user JadeXyan on Reddit with the cards and credits required for levelling units up to level 13.

[image: Table]

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/cncrivals/comments/a4exg3/how_long_is_the_route_to_max_the_cards/)